# Consultar si columna existe mysql

Tags: mysql

Estimados: tengo una hoja de calculo en donde tengo diferentes columnas dependiendo de los meses (no siempre son iguales) pero la tabla se llama siempre igual y tengo una consulta en mysql en donde tabulo la información, acá va un ejemplo de lo que hago

(esto serian los datos de un mes )

```
planilla 
id |nombre1|nombre3|nombre4
1  | 100   |  a    |   x
2  | 200   |  b    |   y
```

(esto serían los datos de otro mes)

```
planilla 
id |nombre1|nombre2|nombre4
1  | 100   |  a    |  xx
2  | 200   |  b    |  yy
```

lo que necesito saber es como saber si existe una columna en especifico porque todos los meses tendré un rango de columnas diferentes (del 1 al 20 por ejemplo) y así hacer solo 1 consulta con todos los datos y si los encuentra me los trae y si no que me de un 0 , porque ahora tengo

```
select nombre1,nombre2,nombre3,nombre4,nombre4
from planilla
```

pero al hacer eso me da un error que no encuentra la columna [Err] 1054 - Unknown column XXXX in 'field list'

¿Cómo puedo evaluar cada columna si es que existe en la tabla? he visto el "if exists" pero no me funciona.

Muchas gracias!

**Actualización**:

acá tengo el ejemplo real acotado

Acá tengo el ejemplo acotado, el problema lo tengo en la segunda línea, porque el campo "S002" no siempre existe, entonces no se como preguntar antes de hacer la suma si es que existe, de no existir que me tire un 0

```
select dni,Codigo,
SUM(IF(PROYECTO = 'GENERAL', `S001`, 0)) G001,
SUM(IF(PROYECTO = 'GENERAL', `S002`, 0)) G002,
SUM(IF(PROYECTO = 'SEN',`S001`,0)) as 'S001','',
SUM(IF(PROYECTO = 'PRO',`S001`,0)) as 'P001','',

from base
GROUP BY dni,Codigo
ORDER BY dni
```

Comment: y porque no haces select *?

Comment: @gbianchi claro, tu solucion es buena, no te habia entendido yo, no da error seguro, pero igual le revienta la memoria al sistema si la tabla es enorme :-)  El problema es que luego no dice que hace con esos datos, ni con que lenguage de programación va a acceder a ellos, o si solo lo quiere para usarlo via phpmyadmin, navicat o cualquier otra cosa similar. o si tiene miles de columnas adicionales aparte de las nombre*

Comment: @masterguru tampoco lo sabemos.. no queda claro.. viene de un excel, no creo que sean muchos datos... la pregunta, en si, es muy confusa...

Comment: perdón, me explico mejor, obtengo los datos de una planilla consolidada en excel mensualente y solo los necesito trabajar en phpmyadmin, no puedo hacer un select * porque tengo que hacer sumas y otras operaciones entre los datos, el problema se me genera que no todas las planillas tienen todas las columnas iguales y debo trabajar con lo que me envian

Comment: dejé otro ejemplo en la pregunta para ver si me logro explicar mejor, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ahora, tu pregunta es una pregunta real.. y no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con lo que preguntabas al principio (o si, pero ahora se la puede responder)... No vas a poder hacer un query que lo resuelva, necesitas un query dinamico, y para eso no te queda otra que hacer un procedimiento almacenado...

Comment: o hacer un etl real, que normalice la entrada para que esto no te pase....

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil.

```
Select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='el nombre de su base de datos' and table_name='el nombre de la tabla que quiere' where column_name='el nombre que busca';
```

Si devuelve algo, sí existe.

Comment: claro, pero necesito que se siga ejecutando la sentencia si es que encuentra un error de "no encontrado la columna" ,